# Tikz matrix node in beamer with fragile option AND \onslide produces error

Tags: beamer, tikz-matrix, fragile

When drawing a `tikz picture` entailing a `matrix of nodes` in `beamer` it is needed to turn on beamer option `fragile`. This works fine. However, when also applying an `\onslide<x-y>{}` within or around the tikz picture it produces an error: "Package pgf Error: Single ampersand used with wrong catcode.". One work around is to activate `ampersand replacement=\&` in the `tikzset` and then transform all `&` to `\&`. But I would like to keep the `&`, since I often transfer table content into these nodes.

So my question is, how is it possible to activate the `fragile` option in `beamer` to maintain `&` as node seperators AND make use of `\onslide<x-y>{}` within a tikz picture entailing a node matrix? Or is the only way to employ `ampersand replacement=\&`?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]

%\onslide<1-1>{ %<-- when being activated produces error: "Package pgf Error: Single ampersand used with wrong catcode."

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{table/.style={matrix of nodes}}
    
    \node[matrix,table] {Node 1 & Node 2 \\};   
    
\end{tikzpicture}
%}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using fragile content as argument of a macro is often problematic. You can simply avoid this by using an environment instead of a macro:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{onlyenv}<1-1>
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{table/.style={matrix of nodes}}
    
    \node[matrix,table] {Node 1 & Node 2 \\};   
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{onlyenv}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```