# Beamer animation inside Tikz matrix of nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-matrix, animations

In a Beamer presentation, I use Tikz to make some fancy figures.
Usually I can animate them with `\onslide` etc...

But, here I have an error while using the `\matrix` command (it's the first time I use it).

```
\documentclass[10pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage [francais]{babel}
\usepackage [T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage [utf8]{inputenc}

\usetheme{Boadilla}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}


\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of nodes] (M) at (0,0){
Subject & a & b & c & d \\
1 & 2 & 1 & 4 & \onslide<2->{7}\\
%1 & 2 & 1 & 4 & 7\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The error I got :

```
"! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a
semicolon?."
```

If I remove the `\onslide{}`, all work fine.

I tried to remove the "matrix of nodes" option and inserting all cell inside `\node{}` command, this works but for big matrix, I need to add `\node{}` command everywhere and it becomes less "readable"

```
\begin{tikzpicture}                                                                                                                                              
\matrix (M) at (0,0){                                                                                                                                            
\node{1}; & \onslide<2->{\node{2};}\\                                                                                                                              
};                                                                                                                                                               
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Do you have any idea here ?

It "seems" to be related to [this issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/581589/tikz-matrix-node-in-beamer-with-fragile-option-and-onslide-produces-error) but :

- the animation is OUTSIDE the tikzpicture and I need it for several different cells
- I don't really have the same error message (`Package pgf Error: Single ampersand used with wrong catcode.`.)

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank for your comment, minimal code that reproduce the error added !

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `overlay-beamer-styles` library like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usetheme{Boadilla}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}


\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of nodes] (M) at (0,0){
Subject & a & b & c & d \\
1 & 2 & 1 & 4 & |[visible on=<2->]| 7\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That works nice !! Thank you very much !
I do not really understand what the additional tikz-library actually do. No chance that this affect my others (workking) tikzpicture in some way ?

Comment: @Donut This is very unlikely to have any effect on your other tikz pictures (unless you happen to use the exact same names like `visible on` for your styles)